# SQL query to get latest record for all distinct items in a table

Tags: mysql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of all sales defined like:

```
mysql> describe saledata;
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SaleDate          | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| StoreID           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| Quantity          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| Price             | decimal(19,4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| ItemID            | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I need to get the last sale price for all items (as the price may change).  I know I can run a query like:

```
SELECT price FROM saledata WHERE itemID = 1234 AND storeID = 111 ORDER BY saledate DESC LIMIT 1
```

However, I want to be able to get the last sale price for all items (the `ItemID`s are stored in a separate item table) and insert them into a separate table.  How can I get this data?  I've tried queries like this:

```
SELECT storeID, itemID, price FROM saledata WHERE itemID IN (SELECT itemID from itemmap) ORDER BY saledate DESC LIMIT 1
```

and then wrap that into an insert, but it's not getting the proper data.  Is there one query I can run to get the last price for each item and insert that into a table defined like:

```
mysql> describe lastsale;
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| StoreID           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| Price             | decimal(19,4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| ItemID            | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the greatest-n-per-group problem that comes up frequently on Stack Overflow.

```
INSERT INTO lastsale (StoreID, Price, ItemID)
  SELECT s1.StoreID, s1.Price, s1.ItemID
  FROM saledata s1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN saledata s2
    ON (s1.Itemid = s2.Itemid AND s1.SaleDate < s2.SaleDate)
  WHERE s2.ItemID IS NULL;
```